# Can't split dataframe into equal buckets preserving order without introducing Xn. prefix

Tags: r

I am trying to split an ordered data frame into 10 equal buckets. The following works but it introduces an X1., X2., X3. ... prefix to each bucket, which prevents me from iterating over the buckets to sum them.

```
num_dfs <- 10
buckets<-split(df, rep(1:num_dfs, each = round(nrow(df) / num_dfs)))
```

Produces a df[10] that looks like:

```
$`10`
       predicted_duration actual_duration
177188         23.7402944               6
466561         23.7402663              12
479556         23.7401721               5
147585         23.7401666              48
```

Here's the crude code I am using to try to sum the groups.

```
for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
  p<-sum(as.data.frame(df[i],row.names=NULL)$X1.actual_duration) # X1., X2.,
  print(paste(i,"=",p))
}
```

How do I remove the `Xn.` grouping prefix or programmatically reference it using the index `i`?

Here's a similar reproducible example:

```
df<-data.frame(actual_duration=sample(100))
num_dfs <- 10
df_grouped<-as.data.frame(split(df, rep(1:num_dfs, each = round(nrow(df) / num_dfs))))

for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)){
  p<-sum(df[i]$actual_duration) # does not work because postfix .1, .2.. was added by R
  print(paste(p))
}
```

Comment: @Hack-R I added an example at the end, although the behavior is a bit different in this case--R adds a postfix .1, .2, .3, rather than a X1. prefix.

Comment: In your reproducible example `p<-sum(df_grouped[i])` seems to be working. Also `lapply(buckets, function(x) sum(x$actual_duration))` might be helpful in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what your issue is, but if you are just trying to get the sum by group couldn't you use

```
 library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(actual_duration=sample(100))

 df %>% 
   arrange(actual_duration) %>% 
   mutate(group = rep(1:10, each = 10)) %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(sums = sum(actual_duration))
```

alternatively if you want to keep the list format

```
df %>% 
  arrange(actual_duration) %>% 
  mutate(group = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10))) %>% 
  split(., .$group)  %>% 
  map(., function(x) sum(x$actual_duration))
```

Comment: Thank you -- that works but it doesn't preserve the order. The list is ranked, and I am trying to sum the deciles (I need to compare the ranked order of sum of decile 1 with the randomized order sum of decline, to generate a gain/loss linear regression table. I will post that as a separate question.

Comment: without the `predicted_duration` in your data.frame it is difficult to understand exactly what you are looking for. It would be helpful if you provided a full outline of the input data and expected results.

Comment: All I had to do was remove the arrange() statement, which was resetting my order. Thanks again!